# How to avoid branching and modifying data when generating dicts from lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Sorry for the title - I didn't come up with something more descriptive..

Imagine you have given data like this:

```
given = [('name', 'foo'), ('attr1', 42), ('attr2', 'hello world'), ('name', 'bar'), ('attr1', 3.1416)]
```

and you want to turn it into a dict of dicts by linearly iterate `given` and generate keys by looking for `'name'`:

```
def convert_data(given):
    result = {}
    current_name = ""
    for key, value in given:
        if key == "name":
            current_name = value
        else:
            assert current_name
            result.setdefault(current_name, {})[key] = value
    return result
```

```
>>> convert_data([('name', 'foo'), ('attr1', 42), ('attr2', 'hello world'), ('name', 'bar'), ('attr1', 3.1416)])
{'bar': {'attr1': 3.1416}, 'foo': {'attr1': 42, 'attr2': 'hello world'}}
```

Is there a way to do this more elegantly? (E.g. by splitting `given` into chunks beginning with `('name': ..)` and returning a generator instead of modifying `result`)

**Update**:

Taking `itertools.groupby()` into account (thanks to [Rakesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532312/rakesh)) you can write something like this:

```
def convert_data(given):
    it = iter([list(pairs) for _, pairs in groupby(given, lambda pair: pair[0]=='name')])
    return {name: dict(attrs) for (*_, (_, name)), attrs in zip(it, it)}
```

```
>>> convert_data([('name', 'foo'), ("name", "helmut"),('attr1', 42), ('attr2', 'hello world'), ('name', 'bar'), ("attr3", "value3"), ("name", "albert")])
{'bar': {'attr3': 'value3'}, 'helmut': {'attr1': 42, 'attr2': 'hello world'}}
```

.. which does not need branching or modify contents of variables and yet handles the case when more than one `name` element is given in a row (only the last one is taken into account)

But it still has two disadvantages:

- all generators have to be unpacked, before defining the resulting `dict` generator (I guess because `zip()` together with  `groupby()` invalidates them on the way)
- it's not very readable

Who comes up with a more readable version?

Comment: You requires 'name', and as first item, so you can simplify. You create the dict also when you get name. and then you use dict constructor removing first item,..

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.groupby`.

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby

given = [('name', 'foo'), ('attr1', 42), ('attr2', 'hello world'), ('name', 'bar'), ('attr1', 3.1416)]
result = {}
key = ""
for k,v in groupby(given, lambda x: x[0]=='name'):
    if k:
        _, key = list(v)[0]
    else:
        result.setdefault(key, dict()).update(dict(v))
        
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'bar': {'attr1': 3.1416}, 'foo': {'attr1': 42, 'attr2': 'hello world'}}
```

Comment: `groupby` helps but you still have to create two variables `result` and `key` you have to modify and have branches on the way

Answer (score 0):

Try defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(dict)
name = None
for k, v in given:
    if k == "name":
        name = v
    else:
        result[name][k] = v

print(dict(result))
```

Output:

```
{'foo': {'attr1': 42, 'attr2': 'hello world'}, 'bar': {'attr1': 3.1416}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert each of the `attr, value` pairs to `name, attr, value` triplets by traversing the input with [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) (and then filter out the `attr == 'name'` ones). Instead of `dict.setdefault` you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools as it

given_with_name = it.accumulate(given, lambda x, y: y[1:] if y[0] == 'name' else (x[0], *y))
given_with_name = (x for x in given_with_name if len(x) == 3)

result = defaultdict(dict)
for name, attr, value in given_with_name:
    result[name][attr] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

generator function that yields dict convertible tuples

```
given = [('name', 'foo'), ('attr1', 42), ('attr2', 'hello world'), ('name', 'bar'), ('attr1', 3.1416)]

def chunknames(l):
    j = 0
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        if(l[i][0] == 'name'):
            yield l[j][1],dict(l[j+1:i])
            j=i
    yield l[j][1],dict(l[j+1:])

print( {k:v for k,v in chunknames(given)} )
```

generator function that yields dict convertible lists (chunked lists)

```
given = [('name', 'foo'), ('attr1', 42), ('attr2', 'hello world'), ('name', 'bar'), ('attr1', 3.1416)]

def chunknames(l):
    j = 0
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        if(l[i][0] == 'name'):
            yield l[j:i]
            j=i
    yield l[j:]

print( {c[0][1]:dict(c[1:]) for c in chunknames(given)} )
```